# Unable to start tomcat via cron in FreeBSD

Tags: tomcat, cron

We are having issues starting Tomcat via cron in FreeBSD 10, the script works fine from shell.

Script:

```
pid=$(ps -auxwww | grep java | grep 'tomcat' | awk -F' ' '{print $2}');
echo "NODE PID = $pid"
echo $JAVA_HOME >> $logFile
if [ ! "$pid" ] ; then
    echo "NODE NOT FOUND"
    #date "+-------------- %d.%m.%Y %H:%M ---------------" >>$logFile;
    echo "\n Tomcat is not running.\n"  >>$logFile;
    /usr/home/xxxxx/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/catalina.sh start >     somefile.txt
    sleep 8;
    pid2=$( ps -auxwww | grep java | grep 'tomcat' | awk -F' ' '{print $2}');

/usr/home/xxxxx/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/catalina.sh start > somefile.txt this line does'nt seem to work
```

Any clue for sorting this?

Comment: This Question may be better suited to the [Server Fault Stack Exchange](http://serverfault.com).